# Order rows in R

Tags: r, row

It is probably the simplest question, but I am really stuck. I have a data like this

```
> SALARY
   salary    X0  X1 total        BR        GDis        BDis          WOE           IV
1     225    27   4    31 12.903226  0.05803456  0.16515277 -1.045832158 1.120277e-01
2     226    66  17    83 20.481928  0.14186226  0.70189926 -1.598933265 8.954618e-01
3     227   779 102   881 11.577753  1.67440461  4.21139554 -0.922336431 2.339959e+00
4     228  2953 256  3209  7.977563  6.34726163 10.56977704 -0.509975226 2.153378e+00
5     229  7349 544  7893  6.892183 15.79614822 22.46077622 -0.352004382 2.345978e+00
6     230  6007 451  6458  6.983586 12.91161551 18.62097440 -0.366161268 2.090546e+00
7     231  5477 363  5840  6.215753 11.77241854 14.98761354 -0.241464713 7.763561e-01
8     232  1372  70  1442  4.854369  2.94901556  2.89017341  0.020154903 1.185958e-03
9     233   496  26   522  4.980843  1.06611641  1.07349298 -0.006895275 5.086346e-05
10    234   196   7   203  3.448276  0.42128794  0.28901734  0.376829847 4.984351e-02
11    235   200   8   208  3.846154  0.42988565  0.33030553  0.263501162 2.623948e-02
12    236    68   7    75  9.333333  0.14616112  0.28901734 -0.681777107 9.739610e-02
13    237    65   1    66  1.515152  0.13971284  0.04128819  1.219012607 1.199809e-01
14     NA 21469 566 22035  2.568641 46.14607514 23.36911643  0.680396572 1.549736e+01
      Index Bin
1  2.845766  13
2  4.947752  14
3  2.515160  12
4  1.665250  10
5  1.421915   8
6  1.442188   9
7  1.273113   7
8  1.020359   5
9  1.006919   6
10 1.457656   3
11 1.301479   4
12 1.977389  11
13 3.383845   1
14 1.974661   2
```

I need to change row order so that column "Bin" is in a "right" order 1,2,3...14.
ALso there is one more thing, I have data so that Bin is repeated

```
> OUTSTAND_AMOUNT_MRTG1
                 range    X0   X1 total        BR       GDis        BDis         WOE
1         (0,8.88e+05]    68    2    70  2.857143  0.1463656  0.08288438  0.56866111
10                <NA> 45887 2339 48226  4.850081 98.7688069 96.93327808  0.01875895
2  (8.88e+05,1.36e+06]    66    6    72  8.333333  0.1420607  0.24865313 -0.55980414
4  (1.81e+06,2.26e+06]    65    7    72  9.722222  0.1399083  0.29009532 -0.72922230
8  (4.89e+06,7.96e+06]    65    7    72  9.722222  0.1399083  0.29009532 -0.72922230
7  (3.61e+06,4.89e+06]    64    8    72 11.111111  0.1377559  0.33153751 -0.87825787
3  (1.36e+06,1.81e+06]    62   10    72 13.888889  0.1334510  0.41442188 -1.13315012
5  (2.26e+06,2.77e+06]    62   10    72 13.888889  0.1334510  0.41442188 -1.13315012
6  (2.77e+06,3.61e+06]    61   11    72 15.277778  0.1312986  0.45586407 -1.24472083
9  (7.96e+06,9.31e+08]    59   13    72 18.055556  0.1269937  0.53874845 -1.44511133
           IV    Index Bin
1  0.03609931 1.765901   1
10 0.03443259 1.018936   2
2  0.05967086 1.750330   3
4  0.10951972 2.073467   4
8  0.10951972 2.073467   4
7  0.17019025 2.406703   6
3  0.31838219 3.105424   7
5  0.31838219 3.105424   7
6  0.40399344 3.471965   9
9  0.59503146 4.242324  10
```

Basically, Bin is a rank(BR),ties.method "min", because otherwise it shows mean, and because of that 5 and 8 are missing. How can I avoid it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @akrun Bin column should be 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `order`

```
SALARY1 <- SALARY[order(SALARY$Bin),]
row.names(SALARY1) <- NULL
head(SALARY1)
#   salary    X0  X1 total       BR       GDis        BDis          WOE
#1    237    65   1    66 1.515152  0.1397128  0.04128819  1.219012607
#2     NA 21469 566 22035 2.568641 46.1460751 23.36911643  0.680396572
#3    234   196   7   203 3.448276  0.4212879  0.28901734  0.376829847
#4    235   200   8   208 3.846154  0.4298857  0.33030553  0.263501162
#5     232  1372  70  1442 4.854369  2.9490156  2.89017341  0.020154903
#6     233   496  26   522 4.980843  1.0661164  1.07349298 -0.006895275
 #           IV    Index Bin
#1 1.199809e-01 3.383845   1
#2 1.549736e+01 1.974661   2
#3 4.984351e-02 1.457656   3
#4 2.623948e-02 1.301479   4
#5 1.185958e-03 1.020359   5
#6 5.086346e-05 1.006919   6
```

#### Update

Regarding the new question, suppose if your `Bin` is

```
Bin <- c(1,2,3,4,4,6,7,7,9,10)
cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(Bin)>0))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 7 8
```

For, your dataset `OUTSTAND_AMOUNT_MRTG1`, it would be

```
OUTSTAND_AMOUNT_MRTG1 <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(OUTSTAND_AMOUNT_MRTG1$Bin)>0))
```

Comment: why there are only 6 of them?

Comment: ohh, thats it, i got it!

Comment: @MadinaTultabayeva  Just to avoid typing/formatting the full dataset :-)